# How to call applet from web to read excel file and insert data to oracle database?

Tags: java, oracle, applet, oracle-apex

I wrote a java class to read excel file and dump the data to Oracle Database. It needs to reference apache poi libraries( 8 jar files.)  The program works fine in command line.

Now I want to call this java program from Oracle APEX. So I make a jar file with the class (extends JApplet), put the jar file on my web server, and want to call it like this:

```
<APPLET CODE="MyApplet.class" WIDTH=200 HEIGHT=50 archive="http://.../MyApplet.jar">
      <PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="test.xlsx">      
</APPLET>
```

I open the page, it loads the jar file and print this in the java console :

```
basic: Applet loaded.
basic: Applet resized and added to parent container
basic: PERF: AppletExecutionRunnable - applet.init() BEGIN ; jvmLaunch dt 902650 us,         pluginInit dt 5650085646 us, TotalTime: 5650988296 us
basic: Applet initialized
basic: Starting applet
basic: completed perf rollup
basic: Applet made visible
basic: Applet started
basic: Told clients applet is started
```

Then I check my database table, the data is not dumped in. I couldn't find out the problem, no errors printed. What's the problem ?

1. Can applet connect the oracle database?
2. Is this the correct way to pass the parameter to the applet?
3. Must I sign the jar file?

To make it succinct: How to call applet from web to read excel file and insert data to oracle database ? 
Environment : JDK 1.6 ,  Oracle 10.2.0.4

Comment: *"To make it easy : How to call applet from web to read excel file and insert data to oracle database ?"*  That is 'succinct' (to ask) not 'easy'.  ***Nothing*** with applets is easy, and this further complicates matters by connecting to a DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can applet connect the oracle database?

Yes.

> Is this the correct way to pass the parameter to the applet?

Yes.  Though ideally you would deploy the applet using the [deployment toolkit script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit).

> Must I sign the jar file?

It is not vital if the applet is 'phoning home' to the same server in order to connect to the DB.  It is vital if the DB is on another server.

Having said that, due to the [Security Improvements in 7u21](http://blog.eisele.net/2013/04/java-7-update-21-security-improvements.html), an unsigned applet is going to cause some very scary dialogs.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, Now I found a problem that my applet cannot read local system file without defining the full path. the file is in the same directory of the class. I'm using FileInputStream to read the local file, is it possible to just give a file name ?

Comment: *"is it possible to just give a file name ?"*  There should be one question per ..question.  I stretched it to answering 3 for this one, but that is where I draw the line.  If you have another question, ask it on a new question.